# Why didn't Michael plan this step well in advance?

Tags: plot-explanation, prison-break

In the first season of *Prison Break*, Michael and others escape from Fox River Penitentiary.

Michael seemed to have planned each and every step thoroughly. In fact, he went into so much detail as to learn chemistry and get an obfuscated tattoo of the blueprints of the prison. He traps Sara in his love (which turned out to be real) to get the infirmary door open.

But when it came to breaking the window bars, he had to improvise at the last moment. Why didn't he plan anything about breaking the window bars?

Comment: Is it possible that he didn't know about the window bars in advance?

Comment: @F1Krazy: No. He visited the same room for his shots with Sara. That room was his exit point from the prison building.

Comment: But he _did_ plan something - the firehose in the elevator. He was unpleasantly surprised when it didn't work straight away. 0:45 "Is this gonna work? // We're about to find out". 1:18 unpleasant surprise, and TBag asks "what now, genius?". And when what's-his-name sacrifices himself, the plan _does_ work...

Comment: @AakashM: That's what I said. He didn't planned that step well in advance.

Comment: Not following you. 0:29, he says "we gotta get that window out, and we gotta get the bars out" - he knew about the bars. He immediately turns and heads for the firehose cabinet - no sign of indecision or on-the-spot planning. He knows exactly what he's going to try.

Comment: Because the initial escape plan, involving corroding a pipe failed after the said pipe was replaced beneath the infarmary.

Comment: @user10191234: I think that might be the reason. If you write an answer with sufficient references I would accept it.

Comment: But I think it is a plot hole, they would go into the infirmary through the corroded pipe without asking Sara to leave the door open but I do not remember about their plan involving the window.

Comment: @user10191234: Watch the video embedded in question.